# jQuery Dialog pass parameters from script to dialog div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**View:**

```
 <img src="~/Content/images/delete.png" onclick="abc" />
```

**Script:**

```
function abc(blobname, filename, fileextension) {
        $('#my-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
    codeblablabla
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to send parameters blobname, filename, fileextension to my dialog?

**View:**

```
<div id="my-dialog"><div>Are you sure you want to delete file: filename+blobname</div></div>
```

?

I don't want to use viewbag..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<img 
  src="~/Content/images/delete.png"
  data-dialog="Are you sure you want to do this?" 
  data-blobname="blah"
/>
```

And then reference it like this:

```
$("[data-dialog]").click(function(){
  var msg = $(this).data("dialog");
  var blobname = $(this).data("blobname");
  // now build your dialog, using the vars created above
  $('<div />').html(msg).dialog();
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks but how do I use that variable in my view, div dialog? Im not that great with js? I managed to pass parameters in The onclick event so i alrdy know how to pass params to The script

Comment: Sorry but it did't work for me. Instead i just added:

    $("#my-dialog").text("text here with variables");

Before opening dialog

Thanks tho!